# Copy elision of map iterator pair value

Tags: c++, c++11, copy-elision

In the following MVE, does the return value of the `Get` function qualify for copy elision?

**EDIT**

I've change the example somewhat. With Visual Studio 2017 in both Debug and Release builds I see a copy construction on the return statement. Hopefully this is just because I've messed up my `Type` that is assisting me with the debugging.

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>

struct Type
{
    Type()
    {
        std::cout << "Default construction\n";
    };

    explicit Type(std::string obj) : obj(std::move(obj))
    {
        std::cout << "Other construction\n";
    }
    ~Type() = default;

    Type(const Type& other) : obj{other.obj}
    {
        std::cout << "Copy construction\n";
    }

    Type(Type&& other) noexcept : obj{std::move(other.obj)}
    {
        std::cout << "Move constructor\n";
    }

    Type& operator=(const Type& other)
    {
        std::cout << "Copy assignment\n";
        if (this == &other)
            return *this;
        obj = other.obj;
        return *this;
    }

    Type& operator=(Type&& other) noexcept
    {
        std::cout << "Move assignment\n";
        if (this == &other)
            return *this;
        obj = std::move(other.obj);
        return *this;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Type& obj1)
    {
        return os << obj1.obj;
    }

    std::string obj;
};


std::map<std::string, Type> mVariables;

Type Get(const std::string& variableName)
{
    const auto variableIt = mVariables.find(variableName);
    if(variableIt==std::end(mVariables)) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Unknown variable requested.");
    }
    return variableIt->second;
}

int main()
{
    mVariables.emplace(std::make_pair("key", Type("value")));
    const auto value = Get("key");  
    std::cout << value;
    return 0;
}
```

The above example provides the following output, which raises a few questions about `make_pair`, but that is not a discussion for here. I guess my confusion is, what in this example prevent the copy elision occurring?

```
Other construction
Move constructor
Move constructor
Copy construction
value
```

Comment: The temporary copy for the return value can be elided, and the compiler might be able to copy-construct the variable `value` in the `main` function directly from the string in `variableIt->second`. On the other hand, this example is maybe a little *to* minimal, and the compiler might be able to skip copying altogether since `value` is never used.

Comment: Good point.. Should print that returned value.

Comment: Yes it should be elided and second copied or constructed into main::value. What is the alternative? In the bad old days I'd consider returning the iterator's string by const reference, but that only cuts out the copy completely if the caller immediately tests the returned string in some way and discards it, and risks the map entry becoming stale if the caller keeps the reference.

Comment: You can return a `Type const&` to `variableIt->second` object to make it 0-copy.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin - exactly because of Gem Taylor's comment about stale map entries. I cannot guarantee callers won't do something silly like hold onto the reference.

Comment: @tuskcode If they store that reference that will be a learning experience for them.

Comment: A copy from `mVariables["key"]` is necessary. Otherwise, what do you expect `value` to be? An alias to `mVariables["key"]`? That contradicts to the semantic.

Comment: So is that the answer @xskxzr - copy elision cannot work here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before C++17<sup>1</sup>, the semantic of `const auto value = Get("key");` is copy-initializing a temporary object from the returned expression `variableIt->second`, then copy-initializing `value` from the temporary object. So there are basically two copies/moves originally.

The copy/move from the temporary object can be elided by directly constructing `value` from `variableIt->second` according to [N3797](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf) [class.copy] paragraph 31 bullet 3:

> - when a temporary class object that has not been bound to a reference (12.2) would be copied/moved to a class object with the same cv-unqualified type, the copy/move operation can be omitted by constructing the temporary object directly into the target of the omitted copy/move.

This copy is guaranteed since C++17 by preventing the temporary object from being materialized in semantic. The new semantic of `const auto value = Get("key");` becomes copy-initializing `value` from `variableIt->second`<sup>2</sup>.

The copy from `variableIt->second` **cannot** be elided because it does not meet the requirement of copy elision appearing in a `return` statement, i.e. [N3797](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf) [class.copy] paragraph 31 bullet 1<sup>3</sup>:

> - in a `return` statement in a function with a class return type, when the expression is **the name of a non-volatile automatic object** (other than a function or catch-clause parameter) with the same cv-unqualified type as the function return type, the copy/move operation can be omitted by constructing the automatic object directly into the function’s return value

This is reasonable because the lifetime of `variableIt->second` does not end and may be used in future, so `value` cannot be optimized as an alias to `variableIt->second`, thus a copy is necessary.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>The only difference since C++17 is the guaranteed copy elision mentioned in the third paragraph. It is more straightaway (in my opinion) to begin the analysis from the semantic before C++17.</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup>There are several rules combined to conclude this conclusion in C++17, and it is not important for this question, so I emit the quote of corresponding rules from the standard.</sub>

<sub><sup>3</sup>The wording of this rule is changed a little in C++17, while the rule is essentially the same.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you have a play on [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org).

What I see with GCC trunk is that pretty much all of the map and string functions get inlined and the only remaining function calls are to `memcmp` (for the inlined find and string comparison) and to `new` and `memcpy` (for the returned copy).

clang trunk doesn't seem to inline as much. `map::find` is still there but still just one call to `new` and `memcpy`.